# SQLAlchemy database design for revisions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to implement the following need: Store "page" and it's "revisions". Like:

```
class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Page'
    page_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Revision(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Revision'
    revision_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    content = Column(String(32))
    page_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Page.page_id'))
    page = relationship('Page', uselist=False, backref='revisions')
```

I want to be able to get page and it's content transparently like:

```
page = session.query(Page).filter(Page.page_id == 42).one()
page.name 
page.content
```

I read [SQLAlchemy inheritance doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html) but i don't know if i cant do that with inheritance.

Is it possible to do something like that ? How ?

Comment: I would look into "Type 2 data warehouse". Basically keep an effective start date and effective end date, with the latest having the effective end date being null.

Answer (score 0):

you ORM definition above is invalid. The "inheritance" error you're getting when you try to run this code is misleading. You example has nothing to do with inheritance, you don't need it. What you're trying to model is a simple one-to-many relationship between Page (one) and Revision (many). The major issues with your definition:

1. it's missing `__tablename__`
2. `Revision` table missing reference to `Page` (`page_id`)
3. your `page` relationship definition is incorrect

here is the correct definition + complete example (notice that I also added `autoincrement` so you don't have to generate primary keys):

```
class Page(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Page'
  page_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

class Revision(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Revision'
  revision_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name = Column(String(32))
  content = Column(String(32))
  page_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Page.page_id'))
  page = relationship('Page', uselist=False, backref='revisions')


page = Page()
first_revision = Revision(name='first_revision', content='foo', page=page)
second_revision = Revision(name='second_revision', content='bar', page=page)
session.add_all([page, first_revision, second_revision])
session.flush()
session.commit()
for rev in page.revisions:
  print rev.revision_id, rev.name, rev.content, rev.page_id
```

Comment: Question code is here to illustrate the question. I edit it for future readers. Your answer don't solve my question: My question is not clear enough ? I can try to update it.